# Sine and Cosine Power Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have read that sine and cosine can be represented as power series. Power series, as I understand them, are infinite series that can be represented as:

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j (x-x_0)^j$

where $a_j$ is not dependent on $x$. However, I'm not sure how the representations of sine and cosine satisfy this requirement. For example, the formula for $sin(x)$ is given as:

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} x^{2j+1}$

How can I rewrite this in the form, $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j (x-x_0)^j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Git Gud wrote:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} x^{2j+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!}}_{\displaystyle a_{2j+1}} (x-\underbrace{0}_{\displaystyle x_0})^{2j+1}$$

Going a bit further, set $a_j=\begin{cases} \frac{(-1)^{(j-1)/2}}{j!} & j\textrm{ odd}\\ 0 & j\textrm{even}\end{cases}$.  Now $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} x^{2j+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j (x-0)^j$.

Answer (score 0):

The first series you gave converges for all $x$, and is of the right shape, so there is no need to rewrite. (The fact the even powers of $x$ were not mentioned doesn't matter: put them in, with coefficient $0$.)

But in fact for any $x_0$, the $a_j$ can be computed: they are of the shape $\frac{1}{j!}b_j$, where $b_j$ is one of $\pm \sin(x_0)$ or $\pm \cos(x_0)$.
Specifically, $b_0=\sin(x_0)$, $b_1=\cos(x_0)$, $b_2=-\sin(x_0)$, $b_3=-\cos(x_0)$, $b_4=\sin(x_0)$, $b_5=\cos(x_0)$, and continuing to cycle with period $4$ forever.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what the OP wants to know.

Comment: Looks like it. But now OP knows the "general" Taylor expansion of $\sin x$.

Comment: I can't upvote here even though I feel like you did a good thing. I'll upvote you somewhere I feel is appropiate.

Comment: There is no good reason for an upvote.